# asp:button Event not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp button which does not fire event after clicking. The button is inside a update panel.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" CssClass="buttonsmall"  BorderStyle="None" OnClick="btnExportExcel_Click" />
```

I also added the following code on page load

```
   ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExportExcel);
```

C# code

```
  protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   try
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = "List.xls";
                System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
                dgGrid.RowDataBound += gdv_RowDataBound;
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.DataBind();
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                //Apply style to Individual Cells
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                dgGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[12].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                for (int i = 0; i < dgGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = dgGrid.Rows[i];

                    //Change Color back to white
                    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    //Apply text style to each Row
                    row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
                    //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
                    if (i % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[8].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[9].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[10].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[11].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                        row.Cells[12].Style.Add("background-color", "#A59CFF");
                    }
                }
                dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                this.EnableViewState = false;

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.End();
                Response.Flush();
                dgGrid.Dispose();
            }
}
```

Am i going wrong some where

Comment: Put BreakPoint At here `protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and check whether it's hitting or not

Comment: add the script manager in the aspx just above the update panel and try

Comment: As this button is inside gridview how can u directly fire `clickevent` of it.. First of all find that button and then fire clickevent of it

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue

The root cause of the problem was that I had a jQuery validations on the page even though i put causes validation=false on button since jQuery being on the clientside it did not work

The issue can be fixed by adding $("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
n the jQuery click of the button

Comment: ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExportExcel);   These lines in your code did helped me to figure out my problem

Answer (score 0):

If the button triggers an async postback you are most likely receiving an error message behind the scenes since you are modifying the response. Add the following to the `Triggers` collection in the update panel so that the button triggers a full postback...

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportExcel" />
 </Triggers>
```

Then, remove the following line of code which is not needed...

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.btnExportExcel);
```

and make sure you have set the `AutoEventWireup` property of the page directive to `true`...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Comment: I tried adding asp:PostBackTrigger not working and the codebehind is not firing

Comment: I have added more details to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response much appreciated